# How do I calculate offset to \put picture from left bottom page corner?

Tags: graphics

I need to place picture on empty page just from left bottom corner via `\put(x,y){}` command. I can do this after I typtsetting document and measure (approximately) offset by Acrobat Reader and transforme measured values to pt. Then I able to write this:

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{picture}(0,0)
   \put(-149.7,-657.3){\frame{\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}}}
 \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I calculate (define) this values `(-149.7, -657.3)` automaticly using some Tex or Latex tools? Or it possible to reset current coordinates to `(0, 0)` to use `\put(0,0){}` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}%something on the page
 \AddToHook{shipout/background} %or \AddToHookNext 
   {\put(0,-\paperheight){\frame{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's works but I need to paste image for only one page. This code provide background picture for any following pages of document.

Comment: You can use `\AddToHookNext`  if you want only the next shipout.

Comment: It's what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to load the `eso-pic` package which has a `\AtPageLowerLeft` specifier:

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

Other stuff on page, or if need be:
\phantom{Other stuff on page.}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}%
    }%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: hm, you didn't try. This outputs nothing ;-)

Comment: It does if there's anything else on the page, which I presume there is. If not, then a `\phantom{something}` will do the trick. Added that.